# Download file confirmation message, is needed?

Tags: download

Is it needed to show up a confirmation message to the user before downloading any file from Web Application?

If it is needed, when can I show up this message ?

> Do you want to download this file?
>
> [Download]  [Cancel]

Thanks

Comment: How big are the files (are they big enough to warn people about?), what is the target audience (does it involve people with little amounts of internet, such as mobile users or users on certain regions where internet isn't as developed as others)?

Comment: Does your interface inform the user of the file size anywhere?

Comment: Does this happen at a point where the user is otherwise unaware they are about to download a file? Or is it only after a user action specifically for that purpose?

Comment: @Ave not more than 5MB, but a lot of files.

Comment: @AC no, it does not inform.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy No, He is aware, but There is a list of files, He choose one of them and then click download button.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This task is already done through all major browsers. If you start throwing these messages into your web app your users will be frustrated.

Imagine you're at a restaurant, the waiter takes your order, then 5 seconds later he comes back to take your order again. You'd be annoyed that he didn't act on your first answer. You'd probably get up and walk out. That's what your users will do.

Bottom line: **Leave it to the browser.**

---

Extra: If your web app has a nice big shiny Call To Action (CTA) button for the download and you're not sending them malicious content then you're all good to go without extra confirmation.

Comment: I would opt for "then 5 seconds later his supervisor comes back to take your order again." Anyways, +1

Comment: I guess the browser could be the supervisor in this scenario... Or the head chef !? I have to stop thinking about it or I will get hungry.

Comment: The given example is only suitable for browser who actually ask the user, if they want to download the file (e.g. Internet Explorer). Nonetheless, you should leave it to the browser. I'm using chrome and don't get a prompt for the most of the files and this is fine for me. I don't expect something else, so don't do something else.

Comment: What does "CTA" stand for?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit CTA = Call To Action

Comment: @osdavison: Perhaps the acronym in the answer could be expanded so that people who have never heard it before can understand the solution.

Comment: @MichaelSchmidt I guess it's because "Ask where to save each file before downloading" on your Chrome's setting is disabled (which I think is the default value?). Anyway, most of (if not all) popular browsers will have this setting to prompt the user first.

Comment: I would also note that if it's possible to detect if the user is on mobile, depending on the file size, it might be helpful to know "The file is 300MB, please confirm to download" or something like that, no?

Comment: @Bruce Give me that information before I click, then!

Comment: @BruceWayne Put the size on the button: [Download (300MB)]

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit added it to the answer.

Comment: However, if you _are_ sending them malicious content, you should still ask for their permission.

Comment: @pipe yes, that's what I wrote "If...  you're not sending them malicious content... ".

Comment: @RobE: Cheers better

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to add that you really only need confirmations for destructive actions that are hard to undo. It is extremely easy to abort the download if a user decides initiates it by accident or decides that they don't want the file.

Every gratuitous confirmation just adds friction. You're better off focusing on making the action harder to inadvertently activate.

Answer (score 2):

### Don't trust the platform too much

As others have pointed out, browsers the features necessary for download management. *However*, relying on such a varied and volatile platform to make things clear to your users is risky.

### Say it clearly *once*

Make sure the action your users take to initiate the download is crystal clear. Then when the download happens, whatever the browser does with it will come as no surprise.